# php jpeg support

Tags: php

I have complied php with the below options

```
'./configure' '--with-config-file-path=/opt/apache/php/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/opt/apache/php/etc/php.d' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-soap' '--enable-bcmath' '--disable-debug' '--enable-ftp' '--with-curl=/usr/include' '--with-regex=system' '--enable-inline-optimization' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-wddx=shared' '--enable-xml' '--with-gd' '--with-gettext' '--with-mysql' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/lib' '--enable-mbstring' '--prefix=/opt/apache/php' '--with-apxs2=/opt/apache/bin/apxs' '--with-zlib' '--with-openssl' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2/freetype--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib/'
```

but I have no jpeg support.

Am I missing something?

libjpeg and libjpeg-devel are installed

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2/freetype--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib/

there are no space between

--with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2/freetype

and

--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib/

Isn't it?

Comment: +500 for that. Did not see it